# Which Google API's can be accessed using the access-token obtained using Google Service Account

Tags: google-oauth, service-accounts

Referring to the document https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount, was able to obtain an access-token.The above mentioned document doesn't provide any details regarding the API's that can be accessed using Service Account.Can anyone list the API's which can be accessed using access-token obtained from Google service account?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't have an exhaustive list of the support in this area. In general, you should be able to access a Google API if that API does not require the user to do something in a web interface to configure their account before doing API access. Service Accounts can't log in. So if the service needs some interactive input from a user on a Google wesite, often their APIs will not work with Service Accounts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it mean that Service Account won't work with Youtube API? I'm trying to automatically upload video to my own channel using Oauth, without having to authorize access every times.